# В каких случаях rebase можно и нужно делать, а в каких нет?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Мне никак не удается сделать для себя выводы, когда мне следует сделать `rebase`? Прошу опытных товарищей поделиться опытом и высказать критерии, которые влияют на решение о том что нужно сделать `rebase`. А также привести примеры ситуаций, когда его делать не нужно.

Возьмем ситуацию, когда для реализации фичи1 я сделал ветку1. В этот момент ветка master завершена комитом0. Одновременно со мною Вася паралельно реализовал фичу2 в ветке2 и влил ее в master. Ветка2 состоит из комит1, комит2, комит3 и эти комиты попали в master. Мне бы хотелось с помощью GIT привести свою ветку к тому состоянию, как будто бы я сделал свою ветку1 начиная с комита3.

Допустимо ли в моей ситуации применять `rebase`?

Comment: Под ребейзом обычно понимают две разные возможности `rebase -i`: 1) переставить ветку на другой коммит (обычно на актуальный `master`); 2) объединить (squash) коммиты в один. О чём из этого (или о чём другом) вы спрашиваете?

Comment: Я бы хотел отдельно отметить тот момент, что с точки зрения корректности истории мердж зачастую лучше ребейза. Т.е. если взять ту же абстрактную ситуацию с мастером, гораздо лучше, если влитие ваших изменений будет отмечено отдельным конкретным коммитом, чтобы это можно было отследить.

Comment: а почему просто не - находясь в ветке ветка1: `git pull origin master` раз Вася туда пушанул? Помоему логично периодически сводить побочную ветку с мастером.

Comment: @Etki я там написал рекомендацию использовать `merge --no-ff` после ребейза. Буду рад, если что-то полезное добавите.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да там сложно что-то добавить )

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр мы тут написали два ответа, в целом в них есть ответ и на ваш вопрос. Но если вы прочитаете и вопрос останется актуальным - сообщите пожалуйста, я что-нибудь добавлю именно про это.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin да, я уже прочитал, вопросов нет, спасибо.

Comment: у rebase нет общего понятия можно/нужно это вопрос политики команды и больше ничего. Это как с исключениями — кто-то использует постоянно, кто-то время от времени, а кто-то бежит от них как от огня.

Comment: @Abyx, не правда. В команде могут быть различные политики по-поводу rebase/not rebase побочных веток и вообще по работе с побочными ветками.

Comment: В Вашей ситуации это просто must
git fetch
git rebase origin/master

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Сделайте бэкап

Всегда, когда сомневаетесь, делайте бэкап. Сойдёт любой способ:

```
git branch backup
git tag backup
git reflog
```

## Сохраняйте историю!

Если вы ребейзите feature-ветки на master перед мержем, настоятельно рекомендую вам использовать `merge --no-ff`, т.е. форсировать создание мерж-коммита. Без этого будет получаться fast-forward и полностью линейная история.

Мерж-коммиты будут показывать историю работы над проектом, в частности момент мержа feature-ветки и автора мержа (кто пропустил код в master). Начиная с версии 2.6.0 [git умеет отменять (revert) мерж-коммиты](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html). Без мерж-коммита вам придётся указывать точный набор коммитов для отмены, что будет непросто при линейной истории.

## Когда нельзя

- Нельзя ребейзить ничего в стабильных ветках (`master`, `stable`, `production`, `release-1.0` и т.п.).
- Когда вы запушили коммит в удалённый репозиторий (общий) и кто-то его использовал:

  - Ответвился от него
  - Сделал `cherry-pick` в другую ветку
  - Замержил в другую ветку
  - Сослался на этот коммит (GitLab & GitHub в таком случае создают комментарий на странице коммита с упоминанием ссылки)
- Никогда нельзя ребейзить чужие коммиты. Если вы это сделаете, [ночью к вам придёт Линус и сделает ребейз рук на бёдра](https://www.mail-archive.com/dri-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg39091.html).

## С осторожностью

Когда вы ребейзите ветку из более чем одного коммита и вам важна работоспособность в промежуточных коммитах - проверяйте каждый после ребейза. Ребейз переписывает содержимое *каждого* промежуточного коммита, так что если у вас раньше код конкретного коммита компилировался или проходил тесты - не факт, что после ребейза пройдёт.

Если в вашей ветке довольно много коммитов и есть конфликты  - [вам придётся разрешать их многократно](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/10/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase/) (именно потому, что переписывается содержимое каждого коммита). Для сравнения, при обычном мерже вы разрешаете их один раз, собственно в мерж-коммите.

## Когда можно

- Когда у вас есть локальная ветка, которой нет в удалённом репозитории
- Или когда ветка есть в удалённом репозитории, но её точно никто не использовал.

## Когда следует

- Если в вашей команде принято делать ребейз на `master` перед мержем и/или открытием мерж-реквеста.
- Если в вашей команде принято объединять (сплющивать, squash) коммиты в один перед мержем и/или открытием мерж-реквеста.

Вышеуказанные причины работают, если в команде есть также правило не использовать чужие коммиты, которые не замержены в мастер. Если какое-то из условий из раздела "Когда нельзя" выполняется - ребейзить нельзя.

## Тестирование перед мержем

Ребейз даёт некоторое преимущество в тестировании. Предположим, есть ветки `master` и `feature`. Автоматические и ручные тесты, автопроверки кода, профилировщики и прочее показывают положительный результат на обоих ветках. Сохранится ли этот результат после мержа? В общем случае, неизвестно. Даже если мерж без конфликтов, код вообще может не компилироваться после мержа.

Поэтому есть резон сделать ребейз на `master` перед финальным тестированием. Тогда головной коммит `feature` будет идентичен будущему мерж-коммиту. Но этот способ неэффективен по уже описанным причинам:

1. Требует лишней работы по разрешению конфликтов
2. Ломает содержимое промежуточных коммитов

Если есть потребность разрешить конфликты и провести полное тестирование результата мержа, но пока что не мержить в master, лучше применить технику обратного мержа:  `master` мержится в `feature`. Соответственно, мерж-коммит появляется в ветке `feature`.

Полученный мерж-коммит можно тестировать локально, можно запушить в удалённую ветку `origin/feature` для обновления мерж-реквеста, прогона тестов, CI, развёртывания на тестовое окружение и т.п. Когда все проверки пройдены, делайте "прямой" мерж - `feature` в `master`.

Не нужно мержить `master` в вашу ветку просто так, в процессе работы над фичей, это приводит к истории в виде схемы московского метро. Если можете обойтись без мержа `master` в `feature` - обязательно обойдитесь.

Comment: Правильно я понял из ответа, что если в команде не принято эти rebase использовать, то они и не нужны вообще? Я вот просто перед pullRequest делаю мерж мастера, разрешаю конфликты и всё. А зачем этот rebase - непонятно)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мерж мастера немного усложняет граф истории. Если ваши коммиты никто не использовал, то можно сделать squash всех коммитов в один + ребейз на мастер. Тогда разрешать конфликты придётся всего раз, как с мержем. В истории будет всего один лаконичный коммит фичи и мерж-коммит в мастер.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб но это не годится для промежуточного ревью, например.

Comment: _«Нельзя ребейзить ничего в стабильных ветках»_ можно и нужно — `git pull --rebase`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Просто вы столько страшных вещей описали... Мне теперь страшно будет это делать)

Comment: @ixSci я имел в виду стабильные ветки в общем репозитории. А `git pull --rebase` предполагает, что я сам в свою копию стабильной ветки что-то коммичу. Для чего это может быть нужно?

Comment: @ixSci но вообще замечание верное, надо уточнить ответ.

Comment: Не понял, Вы не понимаете зачем может быть нужно `git pull --rebase`? Самый просто примеру: `A` сделал `pull`, потом `коммит` и делает `push`, но не может, ибо в это время `Б` уже сделал `push`. Теперь `A` должен сделать снова `pull`, но если не указать `rebase`, то `pull` создаст коммит. Со временем из таких коммитов вырастает весьма страшная история.

Comment: _"Сделал cherry-pick в другую ветку"_ - но cherry-pick же не связан с исходными коммитами и их исчезновение никак не повлияет на результирующую ветку.

Answer (score 4):

В описанной ситуации граф выглядит например так:

```
> git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
*   12ef823 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'b2'
|\
| * 3b8d7a6 (b2) b2:commit3
| * 5892389 b2:commit2
| * 245fefe b2:commit1
|/
| * ccca93c (b1) b1:commit1
|/
* 406f362 initial commit
```

### rebase

Самый простой и логичный способ обновиться - это rebase

```
> git checkout b1
> git rebase master
> git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
* 5f613a9 (HEAD -> b1) b1:commit1
*   12ef823 (master) Merge branch 'b2'
|\
| * 3b8d7a6 (b2) b2:commit3
| * 5892389 b2:commit2
| * 245fefe b2:commit1
|/
* 406f362 initial commit
```

## merge

В принципе можно вмержить себе мастер, но при этом граф усложнится

```
> git checkout b1
> git merge master
> git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
*   16d4e98 (HEAD -> b1) Merge branch 'master' into b1
|\
| *   12ef823 (master) Merge branch 'b2'
| |\
| | * 3b8d7a6 (b2) b2:commit3
| | * 5892389 b2:commit2
| | * 245fefe b2:commit1
| |/
* | ccca93c b1:commit1
|/
* 406f362 initial commit
```

А после мержа в мастер граф станет еще сложнее:

```
> git checkout master
> git merge b1 --no-ff
> git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
*   1443680 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'b1'
|\
| *   16d4e98 (b1) Merge branch 'master' into b1
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |   12ef823 Merge branch 'b2'
|\ \
| * | 3b8d7a6 (b2) b2:commit3
| * | 5892389 b2:commit2
| * | 245fefe b2:commit1
|/ /
| * ccca93c b1:commit1
|/
* 406f362 initial commit
```

## новая ветка

Вместо rebase можно сделать новую ветку, и перенести туда свои коммиты

```
> git checkout -b b1-1 master
> git cherry-pick ccca93c
> git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
* ebaac4a (HEAD -> b1-1) b1:commit1
*   12ef823 (master) Merge branch 'b2'
|\
| * 3b8d7a6 (b2) b2:commit3
| * 5892389 b2:commit2
| * 245fefe b2:commit1
|/
| * ccca93c (b1) b1:commit1
|/
* 406f362 initial commit
```

но смысла в этом мало, проще сделать rebase

Comment: `можно вмержить себе мастер` - я против вмерживания мастера, если только в этом нет строгой необходимости.

Comment: Ну вы хорошо показали, к какому аду это приводит. )