# Как правильно сплющить (объединить) удалённые коммиты?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, git-push

**Дано:**

Последовательные коммиты `А` и `В`,  запушенные в удалённый репозиторий.

**Задача:**

Сделать из них один коммит `С`.

**Вопрос:**

Беглое гугленье убеждает меня в том, что достаточно что-то типа такого сделать:

```
git squash А
git squash В
git push origin branchname
```

Верно ли я понял и что в процессе может пойти не так?

Comment: @AK, да, коммиты последовательные. Надо влить `В` в `А`. Пытаюсь разобраться в вопросе по этой ссылке но там что-то не нашёл конкретных команд( https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Шаг 0: а можно ли это делать?

> что в процессе может пойти не так

Если коммиты последовательные, то конфликтов изменений не будет. Но поскольку коммиты уже отправлены на удалённый репозиторий, то вам придётся переписывать историю там и что-нибудь может пойти не так у коллег. Вот пара вопросов о том, что и когда можно ребейзить и переписывать:

- [В каких случаях rebase можно и нужно делать, а в каких нет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568660/181472)
- [Откатить уже опубликованный коммит и опубликовать новый, не вызывая мержа у других](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429512/181472)

Кратко: никогда нельзя это делать в стабильных ветках репозитория, где кроме вас есть ещё хоть один разработчик.

## Шаг 1а: сплющивание через rebase -i

Под `git squash` вы наверное понимаете `git rebase --interactive` с последующим выбором опции squash. Действительно, можно сделать так:

Ребейз к третьему коммиту с конца (пред-предпоследнему)

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^
```

откроется такой документ:

```
pick 7423f96 сообщение предпоследнего коммита
pick 91e9b6e сообщение последнего коммита

# Rebase c9e8f38..91e9b6e onto c9e8f38 (2 commands)
...
```

Чтобы объединить два коммита в один нужно сделать squash последнего в предпоследний:

```
pick 7423f96 сообщение предпоследнего коммита
squash 91e9b6e сообщение последнего коммита
```

А потом сохранить документ и выйти из редактора. Откроется новый документ, в котором можно написать сообщение для вновь полученного коммита. По умолчанию там будет:

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:

сообщение предпоследнего коммита

# This is the commit message #2:

сообщение последнего коммита
```

Закомментированные строки не войдут в сообщение. Если оставить пустую строку, то rebase будет прерван.

## Шаг 1б: сплющивание через reset

Поскольку нужно объединить N последних коммитов, отлично подойдёт более простой способ:

```
# сначала очистим индекс (staging area, область подготовки коммита),
# чтобы потом не закоммитить ничего лишнего
git reset .
# поехали
git reset --soft HEAD^^
```

Произошло следующее:

- текущая ветка переставлена на коммит `HEAD^^`, т.е. на два коммита назад.
- изменения всех коммитов вплоть до, но не включая `HEAD^^` собраны в индекс

Можно сделать новый коммит:

```
git commit -m'message'
```

В отличие от способа с rebase, информация об авторе и дате оригинального коммита не сохраняется. Лучше не ребейзить таким образом чужие коммиты, т.к. информация об авторстве обычно важна.

## Шаг 1в: комбинированный подход

Предположим, что в предпоследнем коммите у вас написано нормальное сообщение, раскрывающее суть изменений. А в последнем вы исправили опечатку. Т.е. было бы удобно объединить два коммита, оставив сообщение от предпоследнего.

```
# То же, что и в шаге 1б: собираем содержимое последнего коммита в индекс
git reset .
git reset --soft HEAD^

# "редактируем" последний коммит, добавляя в него содержимое индекса
# (на самом деле создаём новый коммит с тем же сообщением и переставляем на него ветку)
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

## Шаг 2. запушить на удалённый репозиторий

Поскольку вы переписали свою ветку, нужно будет запушить с -f.

```
git push -f origin mybranch
```

Comment: `push -f` -- зло, если репозиторием пользуется хотя бы один человек помимо автора.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko согласен с вами по части стабильных веток, во временных обычно бывает можно переписывать историю. Об этом подробно написано в двух вопросах из "Шаг 0".

Answer (score 5):

Я бы сделал так:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit 
git push -f origin
```

Всё это, разумеется, если у Вас коммиты на конце текущей ветви. В противном случае придётся делать `rebase`.

Answer (score 3):

Нет такой команды как `git squash`, делайте через `git rebase -i`.

```
$ git squash
git: 'squash' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        stash
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/21890252#21890252) ещё советуют создать алиас на squash.

Проблем со сплющиванием двух **последовательных** коммитов не будет. :сли вам нужно влить B в A, то проблем не возникнет. (Так же как и при вливании N последовательных коммитов в предыдущий).

Сложности могут возникнуть в том случае, если между A и B есть другие коммиты.

В общем случае если нужно влить B в A - делайте так.

(переключаемся на нужную ветку)

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4
pick 8394e5a commit
pick 33b90d9 A
pick 5c633cf B
pick 1604c23 yet another commit

# Rebase 76e6ae0..1604c23 onto 76e6ae0
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
~
"~/ansible/test/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" 22L, 780C
```

Приводите к виду:

```
pick 8394e5a commit
pick 33b90d9 A
s 5c633cf B
pick 1604c23 yet another commit
```

Далее выходите с сохранением и пушим изменения в удалённую ветку.

Как обычно: не забываем, что изменение истории через rebase требует `git push -f`, что в общем случае не приветствуется в командной работе.