# Как объединить коммиты через IDE WebStorm?

Tags: git, git-commit, webstorm

Есть WebStorm в нем пишу код и коммичу. Часто нужно "склеить" несколько коммитов на ветке в один коммит, а остальные просто включить в него.

Как это можно сделать в интерфейсе самой WebStorm, а не через git-терминал? Или она такого не поддерживает?

Comment: @Razmik вы испортили форматирование своей правкой. Пожалуйста, прочитайте: [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться, [можно ли объединять коммиты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568660/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%85-rebase-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82).

Comment: [Как проще и надежнее объединить коммиты через консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593051/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Чтобы инициировать операцию rebase**

1. В главном меню выберите VCS | Git | Rebase. Откроется диалоговое окно Rebase Branches.
2. В раскрывающемся списке Git Root выберите соответствующий локальный репозиторий.
3. В раскрывающемся списке «Branch» выберите ветку, которую вы хотите переустановить. По умолчанию выбрана текущая ветка. Если вы укажете другую ветку, она будет проверена.
4. Укажите новую базу и фиксации, которые вы хотите применить.
   Если необходимо, выберите стратегию восстановления и нажмите «Rebase».
   Команда rebase также доступна из всплывающего окна Git Branches в подменю для выбранной ветви.

**Чтобы сделать rebase в интерактивном режиме**

1. Инициировать процедуру rebase.
   Чтобы IntelliJ IDEA попытался воссоздать слияния вместо того, чтобы игнорировать их, установите флажок «Сохранять слияния».
   Git не поддерживает раздачу коммитов, когда включена опция Сохранять сливки.
2. Установите флажок «Интерактивный».
3. Укажите новую базу, диапазон применяемых комманд и стратегию слияния.
   Чтобы просмотреть, какие файлы затронуты в фиксации, выберите фиксацию и нажмите кнопку «Просмотр».
4. Нажмите «ОК». Откроется диалоговое окно Rebasing Commits, отображающее список всех коммитов в указанном диапазоне в хронологическом порядке. Для каждого фиксации отображаются его хэш и комментарий.
5. Определите порядок обработки коммитов, выбрав соответствующие строки и нажав кнопки «Вверх» и «Вниз».
6. В раскрывающемся списке Действие выберите способ обработки каждой транзакции:

   - Чтобы применить коммит как есть, выберите вариант «Pick».
   - Чтобы обновить фиксацию перед ее применением, выберите параметр «Edit».
   - Чтобы игнорировать коммит, выберите опцию Skip.
   - Чтобы объединить коммит с предыдущим коммитом, выберите параметр Squash.

После того, как вы начнете rebase, вас попросят предоставить дополнительную информацию о сдавленных коммитах.
Если затронутые коммиты имеют разных авторов, раздавленное коммитирование будет приписано автору первого коммита.

7. Нажмите кнопку «Rebase». Процесс перезагрузки начинается. Просмотрите журнал изменений в окне инструмента управления версиями, разрешите возникшие конфликты и возобновите перезагрузку.

Comment: В двух словах: Нужно просто поставить флажок `Preserve Merges` после нажатия пункта меню `Rabse`. Ну и флажок `Interactive` тоже нужно на сколько я понял.