# Как из некоторых снимков сделать отдельную ветку?

Tags: git

[image: Как из некоторых снимков сделать отдельную ветку?]

Есть существующая старая ветка `old` в которой вся история из результирующих и промежуточных снимков. Необходимо выбрать из неё только результирующие снимки и создать на их основе отдельную «чистую» ветку, например, `master`.
Решение не обязательно должно соответствовать рисункам, возможно, есть более грамотный вариант, не знаю.
**Рис. 1** — старая ветка.
**Рис. 2** — вариант со слиянием.
**Рис. 3** — вариант с копированием.
**Чёрные** — результирующие снимки.
**Белые** — промежуточные снимки.

Comment: git cherry-pick hash подойдёт?

Comment: Используйте `git cherry-pick hash`

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick а `git rebase -i` тут подойдет не лучше ли?

Comment: Кстати, отличные иллюстрации у вас.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Как работать, чтобы такая проблема не возникала?

«Промежуточные» коммиты нужны и полезны. Очень удобно бывает сохраниться где-то посреди разработки: чтобы попробовать другое решение, чтобы перенести работу на другую машину, просто для спокойствия.

Но в итоговой истории они не очень-то интересны. Более того, я лично не хотел бы, чтобы кто-то через месяцы и годы смотрел, как я изобретал велосипеды, писал по строчке в час и делал дурацкие ошибки. Нет, я хочу один финальный коммит, как будто я сел, возложил руки на клавиатуру и создал шедевр. Возможно, вам тоже так будет удобнее.

Что делать-то?

### 1. Используйте фичеветки (feature branches)

Для работы над каждой задачей [делайте отдельную ветку от `master`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/637273/181472). Делайте в ней сколько душе угодно коммитов. Когда результат будет готов — вы сможете собрать все эти коммиты в один или несколько осмысленных (инструкция ниже) и замержить в `master`.

Мержить рекомендую с `--no-ff`. Так получается более информативная история: видно, где закончились коммиты одной фичи и начались коммиты другой.

- [Подробнее о фичеветках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573773/181472).
- [Про разные модели работы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623355/181472), в том числе с фичеветками.

### 2. Пользуйтесь `commit --amend` для *промежуточных* коммитов

Исправили одну строчку в фичеветке и снова нужно сделать коммит? Проще переписать старый.

```
git add path/filename
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Здесь `--no-edit` означает, что мы не хотим менять сообщение коммита — оставим старое.

> **Важно:** Нужен хотя бы один новый коммит в ветке, который вы будете переписывать. Если вы только что сделали новую ветку от `master`, пока что нельзя делать `--amend`.  Иначе вы [перепишете коммит из `master`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662457/181472).
>
> **Важно:** `commit --amend`, `rebase -i` и другие операции по переписыванию истории [нельзя выполнять в общих (стабильных) ветках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568660/181472) вроде `master`.

## Как объединить коммиты по группам в новой ветке?

Предположим, у нас есть такая история коммитов. «Промежуточные» коммиты обозначены как `bullshit`, а «результативные» — `result x`. Самый новый коммит — сверху.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate

* 71e8ed5 (HEAD -> oldbranch) result 2
* 0955502 bullshit
* cf30c6f bullshit
* d590b3d result 1
* 8266a62 bullshit
* ce5b35c bullshit
```

Пересобрать их в более красивую (что очень субъективно) историю нам поможет команда `rebase -i`.

Сначала сделаем новую ветку, в которой будет результат операции.

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

Поскольку здесь мы хотим заребейзить всю ветку целиком, добавляем `--root`.

```
git rebase -i --root
```

Если нужно переписать историю только до какого-то коммита (не включая его), указываем хеш этого коммита.

```
git rebase -i ce5b35c
```

Открывается редактор с вот таким содержимым. Здесь порядок коммитов обратный: *самый новый коммит — снизу*.

```
pick ce5b35c bullshit
pick 8266a62 bullshit
pick d590b3d result 1
pick cf30c6f bullshit
pick 0955502 bullshit
pick 71e8ed5 result 2

# Rebase 71e8ed5 onto f7569aa (6 commands)
...
```

Что в этой ситуации можно сделать с коммитами? Нам интересны две команды:

```
# p, pick = use commit
# оставить коммит как есть

# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# слить содержимое коммита с ПРЕДЫДУЩИМ коммитом
```

Объединяем (squash) коммиты группами: первый «промежуточный» после каждого результата станет основой нового результата.

```
pick ce5b35c bullshit
s 8266a62 bullshit
s d590b3d result 1
pick cf30c6f bullshit
s 0955502 bullshit
s 71e8ed5 result 2
```

Когда вы сохраните этот текст и выйдете из редактора, откроется новый, с текстом сообщения для нового коммита `result 1`, потом для `result 2` и так далее — столько раз, сколько коммитов вы хотите в итоге оставить. Первым будет самый старый, последним — самый новый. По умолчанию вам предлагается вот такой шаблон:

```
# This is a combination of 3 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:
bullshit

# This is the commit message #2:

bullshit

# This is the commit message #3:

result 1

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
```

Когда вы отредактируете и сохраните все новые сообщения, `rebase -i` завершится. Получится примерно такая история:

```
* 588a7ac (HEAD -> newbranch) result 2
* 2713fda result 1
```

Comment: @akp она не от конца старой, она совсем отдельная (orphaned). Если хотите чтобы ветки где-то внизу соединялись, то выберите коммит где они разветвятся и делайте до него `rebase- i abc123`.

Comment: @akp а старая ветка и так осталась неизменной, мы же её не трогали совсем.