# Помогите правильно организовать работу с git

Tags: git, github, развертывание, git-commit, репозиторий

У нас имеется один репозиторий и один проект развернутый локально.

1. Я сделал коммит `commit1`, задеплоил изменения в staging на сервер (например, чтобы показать руководителю, не программисту).
2. Руководитель сказал хорошо, но нужно сделать кое-что другое, совсем другой функционал. А `commit1` пока не деплоить на staging.
3. Я делаю `commit2` в репозиторий, опять деплою на staging.

Все нормально, нужно деплоить в production. Но в репозитории уже есть `commit1` который деплоить в production нельзя, соответственно я в ручную возвращаю старый код в этих файлах и только тогда деплою в production изменения `commit2`.

Как организовать в таком случае работу?

Comment: Используйте `git-flow` - принцип: одна фича-одна ветка из develop (тут стэйджинг). Тогда любые изменения параллельные будут в разных ветках и переключения меж ними - просты.

Comment: Используйте фичеветки! [Как правильно отправить релиз на git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573743/181472), [Правильное именование веток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623355/181472), [Как из некоторых снимков сделать отдельную ветку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711637/181472)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Я понимаю как работать с ветками, я не понимаю что делать когда и `commit1` и `commit2` уже в удаленном репозитории.

Comment: Кроме как в ручную удалять код:)

Comment: @dmitriy а это всё происходит в ветке `master`? тогда лучше `git revert <хеш коммита 1>`

Comment: А если в какой-то фичеветке, то растащить коммиты по разным веткам. Поищу, вроде был вопрос про это.

Comment: ну да, разработку я веду в другой ветке, потом все равно сливаю. так что это не имеет смысла при моей проблеме. Здесь суть проблемы в том, что в удаленном репозитории есть и `commit1` и `commit2`, но в итоге в продакшн мне нужно задеплоить только `commit2`

Comment: @dmitriy в каких ветках эти коммиты на удаленном репозитории? Это существенно. `master` мы не будем переписывать, а свою фичеветку — запросто.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64809/discussion-between-dmitriy-and-nick-volynkin).